# making the output of "find" using mongodb with nodejs look better

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, find

I am using a function to find clients from my mongodb database using node js.
In my query I'm trying to get the function to output the data without the "_id"
but it's not working.

```
function findClient(Fname,res){
    let query = {name:Fname}
    dbo.collection("clients")
        .find(query,{ _id: 0,name: 1 ,last: 1, age:1})
        .toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            result = JSON.stringify(result)
            res.render(`./pages/findRes`,{data:result})
            console.log(result)
        });
}
```

Comment: Share the output too

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use toArray here.

```
function findClient(Fname, res) {
    let query = { name: Fname }
    dbo.collection("clients").find(query, { _id: 0, name: 1, last: 1, age: 1 }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        result = JSON.stringify(result)
        res.render(`./pages/findRes`, { data: result })
        console.log(result)
    });
}
```

Basic example here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/WzCaITFhCHM

This should work.